# Java DefaultListModel weird element-containing issue

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I am writing a Java application with swing components. I have 2 JLists which get their data from a DefaultListModel, being these 2:

```
private DefaultListModel<Module> moduleListModel;
private DefaultListModel<Module> sem1ListModel;
```

Module is a dataclass I have created.

Now the problem is, I want to remove Modules from my moduleListModel, if they are also in the sem1ListModel. I know there are 3 modules in sem1ListModel which are also in the defaultListModel, and the code I use to check if it contains them is:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sem1ListModel.getSize(); i++){
        Module mod = sem1ListModel.getElementAt(i);
                    System.out.println(mod);
        if(moduleListModel.contains(mod)){
            System.out.println(mod);
            moduleListModel.removeElement(mod);
        }
    }
```

This code should be working, as the Modules are both exactly the same, yet it doesn't!
When I print both DefaultListModel to the output window, I get this:

```
    System.out.println(sem1ListModel);
    System.out.println(moduleListModel);
```

sem1ListModel: *[Software development 1 [7 credits], ICT Management 1 [7 credits], DOA I [6 credits]]*
moduleListModel: *[DOA I [6 credits], Software development 1 [7 credits], ICT Management 1 [7 credits], Webdesign 2 [5 credits], Software 1 [5 credits]]*

As you can see, *Software development 1 [7 credits], ICT Management 1 [7 credits], DOA I [6 credits]* are the 3 Modules which are in both DefaultListModels and should be deleted from moduleListModel, yet this doesn't happen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you populate your models? I'm wondering if those `Module`s are different objects without an overriden equals.

Comment: public void LoadModules(ArrayList<Module> modules){
  moduleListModel.clear();
  
  for(Module mod : modules){
   moduleListModel.addElement(mod);
  }

The modules ArrayList is an ArrayList filled with Module-objects. 
sem1ListMoel is filled in the same way.

Comment: Remember, having the same _toString()_ implementation (as shown by your logging) isn't enough for the objects to be equal. You must have _mod1.equals(mod2) == true_ which, if you have not overridden the _equals()_ method in _Module_ is the same as _mod1 == mod2_.

Comment: Then I would have to ask you if the arrayList is the same) Referring back to my comment - are the `Module`s actually the SAME object? Or did you create 2 objects that print out the same thing in `toString` but are different when compared by `equals`?

Comment: You're right, .equals() of two the same Modules returns false. I'll have to override the equals

Comment: `DefaultListModel` does not implement `Collection` because of historical reasons. If you are manipulating list models, it's better to use a collection such as a `List` and then you can use methods such as `retainAll` and `removeIf`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just make an answer from the comments so this doesn't hang about.

The problem is that the `Module` objects are in fact different instances, and did not have `equals` overridden. This means that, even though they printed the same thing via the overridden `toString`, the model treated them as distinct objects and did not perform the removal.

The standard way to fix this is to override `equals` (and `hashCode` in case you ever want to use a hashing data structure).